# Python format incomplete date to YYYYMM

Tags: python-3.x, dateparser

As a start, I am extremely new at Python.

I am receiving an Excel file where the date field is incomplete. The value displays as "190808" (YYMMDD) instead of "2019-08-08".

Part of my automation attempt is to move the file to a different location, where the file is renamed. I want to use the date field to change the file name to the file description and date (e.g. "Sales figures 201908").

The code I have only works if the date format is

```
str(df['Bank date'][0].strftime("%Y%m"))
```

I have tried dateparser with the following:

```
dateparser.parse(df['Bank date'][0].strftime("%Y.%m"))
```

The error I am receiving is `'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'strftime'`

Any help will do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I modified it slightly and built my own date-string using slicing.

```
vOldDate = str(df['Bank date'][0])
vNewDate = '20' + vOldDate[:2] + '.' + vOldDate[2:4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy is interpreting the date as an integer. To use dateparser, you need to convert that value into a string first, then parse that string, and then format the result:

```py
dateparser.parse(str(df['Bank date'][0])).strftime("%Y.%m")
```

Since the input format is expected, you should specify it to ensure you get the right date:

```py
>>> dateparser.parse(str(190808), date_formats=['%y%m%d']).strftime("%Y.%m")
'2019.08'
```